Prisma and Jest mocked data
I'm using Jest and jest-mock-extended to do unit testing on some more complex functions in my code. However I ran into an issue where I need to get nested data or something from prisma.
For example:
primsa.person.findFirstOrThrow({where: {id: 1}}).posts()

When I just run this code: primsa.person.findFirstOrThrow({where: {id: 1}}) Jest works great and gets the mocked data, but when I add the .posts() I get an error saying TypeError: person.posts is not a function.
I do my mocked person data like so:
mockPrisma.person.findUniqueOrThrow.mockResolvedValue({
    id: 1
    name: 'John Smith'
});

I understand why this error occurs, but I can't work out the syntax to get the mocked posts in there as everything I try throws a TS error.
Things I tried (assume data between the []):
mockPrisma.person.findUniqueOrThrow.mockResolvedValue({
    id: 1
    name: 'John Smith',
    posts: mockPrisma.post.findMany.mockResolvedValue([]);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

mockPrisma.post.findMany.mockResolvedValue([])

mockPrisma.person.findUniqueOrThrow.mockResolvedValue({
    id: 1
    name: 'John Smith',
    posts: mockPrisma.post.findMany
});


Don't mock what you don't own - Prisma has a large, complex API, and if you create test doubles of it you're only testing that your code works against your assumptions, not the real thing.
